# wso2 api manager APIKEY authentication version 4.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a requirement to use apikey as authentication protocol for API where i need to change the header parameter name into "paymentkey:" which is by defualt "apikey:", when apikey is coming into request. How to get it done.

i changed the runtime configuration on publihser portal but that is only used for oauth2 or basic authentication. and then i add this
[apim.devportal]
api_key_alias = ""
property in .toml file this also not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the current product versions. However, this will be added as a new feature in the future versions [1]

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/1672